# Check if hash is present, if not then add hash

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect if there is a hash present and if not then add a hash to the URL using.  I've read multiple posts on stack trying to find the solution but I can't seem to get my code to work.

```
if(window.location.hash == ''){
window.location = $("#home").attr('href');
}
```

That code actually redirects the site to http://www.sitename.com/undefined
Which is a 404 error page

I've been wracking my head as to why and I just can't figure it out..

The code for the "home" section is:

```
<div class="panel">
    <section id="home">
     <div class="content">
      <div id="logo">
       <img src="images/logo.png">
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

The site is using CSS to give the illusion of animated panels, all 4 panels are pushed way outside of the margins of the site and when `panel:target` it is brought into view.  Apologies if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: `#home` is not a valid element `id` on the page, or the selector isn't right. What does the HTML for this element look like?

Comment: Test if the home element has the href attribute too.

Comment: In other words, there should be an element somewhere on the page that looks about something like this: `<a href='#home' id='home'>Home</a>`

Comment: Umm, there's no `<a>` tag with an `id='home'` with a corresponding `href='#blah'`...?

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It seems I was being an idiot and missing the obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the hash using `location.hash`:

```
if(window.location.hash == ''){
    location.hash = '#yourhash';
}
```

The reason you're being redirected strangely is because `$("#home")` doesn't exist and is therefore undefined.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you, it seems I was just missing the obvious logic in front of me.  I'll mark your answer as the right one as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Just a note, it will work either way, but the `#` isn't necessary when setting `location.hash`.